# Jquery toggle two functions auto

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this code, but it does not work :

```
$('.hover_shine').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css('background-position','10px 0');
});
$('.hover_shine').bind('mouseoutt', function() {
    $(this).css('background-position','-380px 0');
});
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.hover_shine').toggle($(this).trigger('mouseover'),$(this).trigger('mouseoutt'));
},500);
```

I'd like to swap between (mouseover,mouseoutt) events for this element every 500 ms

thank you in advance
AGad

Comment: What is mouseoutt ? tt is double

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hgANB/3/ ?

Comment: this provide the same solution ok, and thank you .
but what the problem of toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
var $el = $('.hover_shine'),
    interval;

function h1() {
    $el.css('color', 'red');
}

function h2() {
    $el.css('color', '');
}

function auto() {
    var fn;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        (fn = fn == h1 ? h2 : h1)()
    }, 500)
}
$('.hover_shine').bind('mouseover', function () {
    h1();
    clearInterval(interval);
});
$('.hover_shine').bind('mouseout', function () {
    h2();
    auto();
});
auto();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hgANB/)

Answer (score 0):

try using the events mouseenter and mouseleave instead.

```
$('.hover_shine').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('background-position','10px 0');
});
$('.hover_shine').bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).css('background-position','-380px 0');
});
```

You might be thinking of the old ".toggle()" in jQuery, which has been removed: See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: I think the problem could be in the toggle function, does it right?